# Flutter error: GooglePayButton is imported from both 'flutter_stripe' and a 'pay' packages

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, google-pay

I'm learning how to install GooglePay into a Flutter app. Several tutorials have said to import two packages:

```
import 'package:my_app/flutter_stripe.dart';
import 'package:pay/pay.dart';
```

But both packages have a `GooglePayButton`. Calling this method results in this conflict:

```
Error: 'GooglePayButton' is imported from both 'package:flutter_stripe/src/widgets/google_pay_button.dart' and 'package:pay/pay.dart'.
```

The `flutter_stripe` [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe) says

> flutter_stripe fully supports the Pay plugin from the Google Pay team.

Does that mean we should import both packages? I'm using `Pay 1.08` and `flutter_stripe 2.1.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Make One Like This:

```
import 'package:my_app/flutter_stripe.dart' as Stripe;
import 'package:pay/pay.dart';
```

Now you can call it as **Stripe**  So it wont conflict